# How to merge multiple sets into a single std::set (set union)

Tags: c++, stl, set, stdset

I would like to know if there is any std library or boost tool to easily merge the contents of multiple sets into a single one.

In my case I have some `set<int>`s which I would like to merge.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
std::set<int> s1;
std::set<int> s2;
// fill your sets
s1.insert(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the difference between insert for multiset and merge, in the context of merging. Insert takes O(logn) for each insert, so O(nlogn) in total; where n is size of smaller container. Whereas merge only needs O(n1+n2). The only reason I can think of for using insert is that it accepts any iterator and the fact that the second complexity has a coefficient of three before it. Is there any other strong reason to favour insert over merge.

Comment: Not really, except that, all things being equal, it's the simplest and most general solution.

Comment: This is a suboptimal solution. See Antonio Pérez answer.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r: This is only _sometimes_ suboptimal, implementations may optimize if the range is already sorted.  Someone should check the various implementations and see if any don't do this optimization.

Comment: Not only that: in evaluating `std::set_union()`'s performance you should take into account the cost of calling `std::set::insert()` repeatedly.

Comment: True. I did not consider the insertion in case the output is not set. Well okay this way both are in O(n*log(n)) (assumed sets are equal). Sorry for ranting.

Answer (score 52):

Looks like you are asking for [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union).

Example:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

std::set<int> s1; 
std::set<int> s2; 
std::set<int> s3;

// Fill s1 and s2 

std::set_union(std::begin(s1), std::end(s1),
               std::begin(s2), std::end(s2),                  
               std::inserter(s3, std::begin(s3)));

// s3 now contains the union of s1 and s2
```

**UPDATE for C++17/20** (see comment below)

> This solution is suboptimal because `std::set` already checks for
> duplicates on insertion. It would be better to use `std::merge` instead
> of `std::set_union` so that this doesn't happen in two places.

Comment: In case you need not to change the original structures, this solution is the best.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that if the target - s3 is not a set - it will result in duplicates in the result (in case there is some intersection between s1 and s2)

Comment: @DavidConstantine no, it will not. a `std::set` cannot contain duplicates and the results are stored in one.

Comment: This solution is suboptimal because `std::set` already checks for duplicates on insertion. It would be better to use `std::merge` instead of `std::set_union` so that this doesn't happen in two places.

Answer (score 43):

With C++17, you can use [`merge` function of `set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge) directly.

This is better, when you want the set2 elements extracted & inserted into set1 as part of merging.

Like below:

```
set<int> set1{ 1, 2, 3 };
set<int> set2{ 1, 4, 5 };

// set1 has     1 2 3       set2 has     1 4 5
set1.merge(set2);
// set1 now has 1 2 3 4 5   set2 now has 1   (duplicates are left in the source, set2)
```

Comment: en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge .  the Complexity N*log(size()+N)), where N is source.size() , I guess it is better to add the complexity to the answer, because this is the same as insert everyone into it?

Comment: Whyyy does C++ not overload `insert` so you can do merge but copying? It would be as simple as constructing a temporary and merging it: `insert(set input) { merge(set(input)); }`

Answer (score 10):

look what std::merge can do for you

[cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/)