# grouping the values in a map to a list

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have a `std::map<int, data> input` as below structure

```
1 -> data{10, 2, 3, 4, 1}
2 -> data{11, 2, 3, 4, 2}
3 -> data{10, 2, 3, 4, 3}
4 -> data{11, 2, 3, 5, 4}
```

`data` is a class

```
class data {
  int val1;
  int val2;
  int val3;
  int val4;
  int val5;
}
```

I am trying to group all values in the input map to vector of tuple `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, std::set<int>>` (considering those data with `val4 != 5`) i.e.

```
10, 2, 3, {1, 3}
11, 2, 3, {2}
```

What I have tried so far;

```
std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, std::set<int>> uniq;
for (const auto& [_, v] : input) {
    if (v.val4 == 5) continue;
    uniq[{v.val1, v.val2, v.val3}].insert(v.val5);
}

std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, std::set<int>> rtn;
rtn.reserve(uniq.size());
for (auto& [k, v] : uniq) {
    const auto [v1, v2, v3] = k;
    rtn.emplace_back(v1, v2, v3, std::move(v));
}
```

The input `map` and `std::vector<std::tuple<...>>` types are fixed.
Is there any alternative ways to do it using some STL algorithm?

Comment: An alternative in what way? More efficient? More readable? Could you also provide a [minimal reproducable example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I don't  want to create temp map `uniq` and multiple for loops to get to result vector. Is there any STL algo solution for the above q

Comment: Is order of your output vector important?

Comment: You can still use some *"insertion sort"* on `rtn` to get rid of `uniq`, but complexity would be worst.

Comment: Order is not important

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one loop like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

class data {
   public:
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int val3;
    int val4;
    int val5;
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, data> input{
        {1, data{10, 2, 3, 4, 1}},
        {2, data{11, 2, 3, 4, 2}},
        {3, data{10, 2, 3, 4, 3}},
        {4, data{11, 2, 3, 5, 4}},
    };

    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, std::set<int>>> rtn;
    rtn.reserve(input.size());
    for (auto const& [_, d] : input) {
        const auto [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5] = d;
        if (v4 == 5) continue;
        const auto pos = std::find_if(rtn.begin(), rtn.end(), [v1, v2, v3](auto const& t) {
            return v1 == std::get<0>(t) && v2 == std::get<1>(t) &&
                   v3 == std::get<2>(t);
        });

        if (pos == rtn.end()) {
            rtn.emplace_back(v1, v2, v3, std::set{v5});
        } else {
            std::set<int> s1 = std::get<3>(*pos);
            std::set<int> s2{v5};
            std::set<int> s3;
            std::set_union(std::begin(s1), std::end(s1), std::begin(s2),
                           std::end(s2), std::inserter(s3, std::begin(s3)));

            *pos = std::tuple{v1, v2, v3, s3};
        }
    }
}
```

Set merging from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089642/3313819

Comment: `else` branch seems overcomplicated, where `std::get<3>(*pos).insert(v5);` would do the job.

Comment: Note that complexity changes from OP `O(n log n)` to `O(n²)` though. (but depending of input size and hidden const factor it might be better or worse, so as always benchmark if speed is a concern).

Comment: You could sort the `std::vector` and then use the `std::binary_search` instead of `std::find` to get back `O(n log n)`.

Comment: If you sort vector at each iteration, you go into worse `O(n² log(n))`. And if you do insertion sort, the insertion is linear (insertion in the "middle" of vector), and you are still in `O(n²)` finally.

Comment: Right I was thinking before going in the loop, but I forgot it was empty... Silly me...